# FB Iframe App: Use different stylesheets depending on whether the user views the app through my website or through Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebooker, facebook-iframe

I'm developing a facebook app which can be viewed in an iframe on Facebook itself, or as a standalone site (the line between Facebook Connect and iframe apps seems to have blurred...).

The stylesheet I have now looks good on my site, but doesn't look right when viewed through the FB iframe (probably b/c the browser screen is much bigger than the iframe). 
**I'd like to use different stylesheets depending on whether the user is actually visiting my website, or accessing the app through Facebook.**

How can I do this?

(I'm using Ruby on Rails, and Facebooker2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it is viewed as an app facebook sends a bunch of extra request parameters, you can check for those on server side.